# Error React y Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs

soy nuevo en esto de react. 
Tengo que hacer testing de un componente y me sale este error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__\test.js (13.787s)
● TPanel › it encountered a declaration exception
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined
        at TestimonyRow.render (src\TestimonyRow.js:14:180)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:808:34)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent (node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:835:34)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:372:30)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:260:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:47:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:385:34)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:260:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:47:35)
        at mountComponentIntoNode (node_modules\react\lib\ReactMount.js:105:32)
        at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.perform (node_modules\react\lib\Transaction.js:138:20)
        at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (node_modules\react\lib\ReactMount.js:127:15)
        at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform (node_modules\react\lib\Transaction.js:138:20)
        at Object.ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates (node_modules\react\lib\ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:63:19)
        at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules\react\lib\ReactUpdates.js:98:20)
        at Object.ReactMount._renderNewRootComponent (node_modules\react\lib\ReactMount.js:321:18)
        at Object.ReactMount._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules\react\lib\ReactMount.js:402:32)
        at Object.ReactMount.render (node_modules\react\lib\ReactMount.js:423:23)
        at Object.ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument (node_modules\react\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:84:21)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (__tests__\test.js:34:79)
        at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__\test.js:31:1)
        at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)
```

El test:

```
jest.dontMock("../src/App");
jest.dontMock("../src/Body");
jest.dontMock("../src/TestimonyPanel");
jest.dontMock("../src/TestimonyRow");

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';


const Body = require('../src/Body.js').default;
const TestimonyPanel = require('../src/TestimonyPanel.js').default;
const TestimonyRow = require('../src/TestimonyRow.js').default;


describe('TPanel', function() {

    var TPanelComponent = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<TestimonyPanel/>);
    var TRowComponent   = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<TestimonyRow/>);<--ACA EL ERROR

    it("El componente debe estar definido", () => {
        expect(ReactTestUtils.isCompositeComponent(TPanelComponent)).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('El panel debe existir y estar definido como elemento', () => {
        const row = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(TRowComponent, 'Row');
        expect(ReactTestUtils.isDOMComponent(row)).toBeTruthy();
   });

});
```

TestimonyPanel:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Row, Col, Panel} from 'react-bootstrap';

import TestimonyRow from './TestimonyRow';

export default class TestimonyPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.testomonialsList = [
            { "_id" : "DsEr75J2ZfA3BJAih", "name" : "Felipe Loyola", "organization" : "Pathkan", "body" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rutrum leo nisi, quis accumsan risus pulvinar quis. In ut dui molestie, sodales urna non, tincidunt dui.", "photo": "profile-photo.png" },
            { "_id" : "p6d4MTMGCAuT4bZLP", "name" : "Víctor Barría", "organization" : "Pathkan", "body" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rutrum leo nisi, quis accumsan risus pulvinar quis. In ut dui molestie, sodales urna non, tincidunt dui.", "photo": "profile-photo.png" },
            { "_id" : "vsCMxdHd8t7to7W4v", "name" : "Daniel Peña", "price" : "99", "owner" : "GQyETWRDXisfYKnnM", "photo": "profile-photo.png" }
        ];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Panel 
                header="Testomonials" 
                bsStyle="success">
                {this.testomonialsList.map((t) => (
                  <TestimonyRow key={t._id} testimony={t} />
                ))}
            </Panel>

        );
    }
}
```

TestimonyRow:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Row, Col, Panel, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class TestimonyRow extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={"./images/"+this.props.testimony.photo} responsive thumbnail />
                </Col>
                <Col md={10}>
                    <strong>{this.props.testimony.name}</strong> from {this.props.testimony.organization}
                    <p>{this.props.testimony.body}</p>
                    {/*<blockquote>
                      <p>{this.props.testimony.body}</p>
                      <footer>{this.props.testimony.name} from <cite title="Source Title">{this.props.testimony.organization}</cite></footer>
                    </blockquote>*/}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

En esta sección de tu código:

```
export default class TestimonyRow extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
```

Estás ignorando pasar el parámetro con los props en TestimonyRow:

```
export default class TestimonyRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que a simple vista y sin probar el código no se me ocurre lo que puede estar sucediendo.

Lo que si te puedo decir es que te sobran paréntesis en la función `map` del método `render` de tu componente `TestimonyPanel`:

```
{ this.testomonialsList.map(t => <TestimonyRow key={t._id} testimony={t} />) }
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas el constructor en una clase que extiende de `Component` para declarar ese array. Simplemente, deja el array como un atributo de la clase.

(no necesitas hacer `extends` de `React.Component` dado que ya hiciste el import de `Component`).

Un consejo muy importante, no necesitas usar una clase debido a que tu componente no tiene estado (stateless component), para esto, basta con escribir tu componente como una función pura, así:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Panel, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default () => (
  <Row>
    <Col md={2}>
      <Image src={"./images/"+this.props.testimony.photo} responsive thumbnail />
    </Col>
    <Col md={10}>
      <strong>{this.props.testimony.name}</strong> from {this.props.testimony.organization}
      <p>{this.props.testimony.body}</p>
    </Col>
  </Row>
);
```